# How can I compact this code for sending info to the view from the Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, eloquent

Here's my edit function in the controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $game = Game::find($id);
    // build list of team names and ids
    $allTeams = Team::all();
    $team = [];
    foreach ($allTeams as $t)
        $team[$t->id] = $t->name();
    // build a list of competitions
    $allCompetitions = Competition::all();
    $competition = [];
    foreach ($allCompetitions as $c)
        $competition[$c->id] = $c->fullname();
    return View::make('games.edit', compact('game', 'team', 'competition'));
}
```

I am sending data in order to display in a select list. I know about Eloquent ORM method Lists, but the problem is as far as I know it can only take property names as an argument, and not methods (like `name()` and `fullname()`).

How can I optimize this, can I still use Eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into [`attributes` and `appends`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json). You can do what you would like by adjusting your models.

**Competition**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Competition extends Model
{

  protected $appends = ['fullname'];
  ...
  public function getFullnameAttribute()
  {
    return $this->name.' '.$this->venue;
  }
}
```

**Team**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{

  protected $appends = ['name'];
  ...
  public function getNameAttribute()
  {
    return $this->city.' '.$this->teamName;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $game = Game::find($id);
    $team = Team::get()->lists('id','name');
    $competition = Competition::get()->lists('id','fullname');
    return View::make('games.edit', compact('game', 'team', 'competition'));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately lists() cannot use custom attributes. For that, you need a collection. Solution: `Competition::get()->lists('fullname', 'id');`

http://www.neontsunami.com/posts/using-lists()-in-laravel-with-custom-attribute-accessors

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk good catch. I updated the answer to reflect this. I might limit the select as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of (aside from using the map functionality of Eloquent collections) is to overwrite the `toArray` method in your model to add some custom attributes.

Eg.

```
public function toArray()
{
    return array_merge(parent::toArray(), [
        'fullname' => $this->fullname(),
    ]);
}
```

This will allow you to use something like:

```
$competition = $allCompetitions->fetch('fullname');
```

**Although**:

In saying all this I think the more elegant solution is to just provide the whole competition objects to the view and let the loop where you render them (or whatever) call the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can call model method in view file if they are not related with other models. So if name() & fullname() returns result related to this model then you can use this model methods in view

```
@foreach (($allTeams as $t)
    {{ $t->name() }}
@endforeach
```

ofcourse you have to pass the $allteams collection from controller to view